# why does MySql request not work correctly?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, database, swing

Bonsoir, je veux afficher le code de fournisseur après le remplissage du champs référence de la table produit c'est pou ça je faix une requete imbriqué mais quant je remplis le champs référence le console m'a affiché java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
voilà mon code :

```
txtRef.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            String sql="Select code from fournisseurs f where f.code in (Select code_fournisseur from produit p  where p.code_fournisseur = f.code)";
            
        try {
            prepared=cnx.prepareStatement(sql);
            
            prepared.setString(1, txtFour.getText().toString());
        
            resultat=prepared.executeQuery();
        
    
        if(resultat.next()) {
        String fournisseur=resultat.getString("code_fournisseur");
        txtRef.setText(fournisseur);
    
        }
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        
    });
```

Comment: SO is an English only site.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! All questions and answers must be [english only](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/).

Answer (score 1):

your code

```
SELECT 
    code
FROM
    fournisseurs f
WHERE
    f.code IN (SELECT 
            code_fournisseur
        FROM
            produit p
        WHERE
            p.code_fournisseur = f.code)
```

has no place holder in form of `?`in tit so you can't add a parameters.

So you should rethink where `txtFour`should be in your query